# How to filter from the response of rest api call

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, marketing-cloud-connect, response, syntax-highlighting

***Updated***
REST API CALL (POST METHOD): /interactions/journeyhistory/search
In the body i am trying to filter the fields which i want.[Example: records with only [activityType : HELLO].

### For that i am using the below syntax in the POST body(json)

```
{
"activityType" : ["HELLO"]
}
```

---

Result : Success

Now, I am trying to do the reverse? Like I want the records who activityType!= HELLO. How to apply not equal to operator here?

### Also, If I have two parameters to search when i apply the same method. It is not working.

```
{
"activityType" : ["HELLO"],
"activityName" : ["STRING"]
}
```

---

It gives results only for activityType not activityName. How to filter based on combination of two parameters ?

I am able to filter on by their definitionId's and activityTypes only. How can i apply filter to other attributes like (eventName, activityName,eventId)?

Thanks!

Comment: We need more context to understand what you are referencing. What API call are you talking about? What is the goal? What is your current state and why is it not working? Please elaborate as I am worried in current state your question will be closed without receiving any answers.

Comment: @Gortonington Updated with all the details now.